# same image name of uploading images not inserting into db

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, hashmap

I am trying to upload images to DB using below code,

MyJsp.jsp

```
<form action="ImageUploadToDB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <img alt="Image1" id="Image11" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="imgtotxt"><br><br>
      <input type="file" id="files11" class="fileUploadimgtotxt" name="files3[]" style="" value="Select Image"> 

      <img alt="Image2" id="Image12" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="imgtotxt"><br><br>
      <input type="file" id="files12" class="fileUploadimgtotxt" name="files3[]" style="" value="Select Image"> 

      <img alt="Image3" id="Image13" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="imgtotxt"><br><br> 
      <input type="file" id="files13" class="fileUploadimgtotxt" name="files3[]" style="" value="Select Image"> 

      <img alt="Image4" id="Image14" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="imgtotxt"><br><br>
      <input type="file" id="files14" class="fileUploadimgtotxt" name="files3[]" style="" value="Select Image"> 

      <img alt="Image5" id="Image15" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="imgtotxt"><br><br>
      <input type="file" id="files15" class="fileUploadimgtotxt" name="files3[]" style="" value="Select Image"> 

      </div>

</form>
```

I am inserting all uploaded images from above form by using servlet like below,

```
final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;

         LinkedHashMap<String, InputStream> fileMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, InputStream>();

        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

            try {
                items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("selected images :"+items);
            if (items != null) {                    
                final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {

                    final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                    if (item.isFormField()) {                       

                    } else {                           
                        fileMap.put(item.getName(), item.getInputStream());
                        //System.out.println("uploaded images  here:"+item.getName());


                    }
                }
            }
        }
try {

        try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");


        Set<String> keySet = fileMap.keySet();

        for (String fileName : keySet) {            
        String sql ="INSERT INTO contacts2 (images) values (?)" ; 
        PreparedStatement statement;

            statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setBlob(1, fileMap.get(fileName));

            int row = statement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("inserted successfully:");

        }

        }
         catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("errror is:"+e);
        }  
         finally{
             try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

If i uploading such as images1.jpg, images2.jpg, images3.jpg, images4.jpg, images5.jpg then my output is :

```
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
```

But if i uploading such as images1.jpg, images2.jpg, images1.jpg, images4.jpg, images2.jpg then my output is :

```
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
inserted successfully:
```

when i check my DB there is image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image4.jpg only.I have no idea why that same name of images not inserting to DB.

Someone tell me where i am wrong?

Updated :
This is for Mr.Keval's answer

```
    fileMap.put((item.getName() + "" + new Date().getTime()), item.getInputStream());

        int count2 =5;
                for (int

 k=0;k<5;k++) {
                System.out.println("for successfully:");
            String sql ="INSERT INTO tbl_MatchImgToImg (Class, Subject, CreatedBy, QimgName, Qimg, AimgName, Aimg) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ; 
            PreparedStatement statement;

                statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                 statement.setString(1, clas);      
                 statement.setString(2, subject);
                 statement.setString(3, uid); 
                 System.out.println("Qimg name is:"+listGet.get(k));
                 statement.setString(4, listGet.get(k));    

                 System.out.println("Qimg is:"+fileMap.values().toArray()[k]);
                 Object bb = fileMap.values().toArray()[k];
                // System.out.println("Qimg is:"+listGet2.get(listgetcount));

                // System.out.println("finallyyyy:"+fileMap.get("files1"));
                 statement.setBinaryStream(5, (InputStream) bb);


                // System.out.println("Aimg name is:"+listGet.get(count2));
                 statement.setString(6, listGet.get(count2));    

                 //System.out.println("Aimg is:"+fileMap.values().toArray()[count2]);
                 Object bb2 = fileMap.values().toArray()[count2];
                 //System.out.println("Qimg is:"+fileMap.get("files2"));
                 //String getval2 = listGet2.get(count2);
                 statement.setBinaryStream(7, (InputStream) bb2);


                int row = statement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("inserted successfully:");

                count2=count2+1;
            }
```

If i upload same images then shows like

```
for successfully:
Qimg name is:image1.jpg
Qimg is:java.io.FileInputStream@f747c0
inserted successfully:
for successfully:
Qimg name is:image4.jpg
Qimg is:java.io.FileInputStream@fd4f30
inserted successfully:
for successfully:
Qimg name is:image5.jpg
Qimg is:java.io.FileInputStream@1b654b9
inserted successfully:
for successfully:
Qimg name is:image7.jpg
Qimg is:java.io.FileInputStream@1303c07
inserted successfully:
for successfully:
Qimg name is:image9.jpg
Qimg is:java.io.FileInputStream@110b3f6

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `LinkedHashMap` with the names of files as keys, when you add two files of the same name (two entries with the same key), the latter will replace the former. This is causing the entries with duplicate names to be replaced. Consider using an ArrayList of a class (that you create) containing the file name and the `InputStream` to store this data.

Edit: my suggestion in code (untested)

```
final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List items = null;

ArrayList<FileWithStream> fileMap = new ArrayList<FileWithStream>();

if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

    try {
        items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("selected images :"+items);
    if (items != null) {                    
        final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (item.isFormField()) {                       

            } else {                           
                fileMap.add(new FileWithStream(item.getName(), item.getInputStream()));
                //System.out.println("uploaded images  here:"+item.getName());


            }
        }
    }
}
try {

    try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");




    for (FileWithStream file : fileMap) {            
    String sql ="INSERT INTO contacts2 (images) values (?)" ; 
    PreparedStatement statement;

        statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setBlob(1, file.getStream());

        int row = statement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("inserted successfully:");

    }

    }
     catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("errror is:"+e);
    }  
     finally{
         try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

with a class like:

```
public class FileWithStream {
    private String name;
    private InputStream stream;

    public FileWithStream(String name, InputStream stream) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public InputStream getStream() {
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i cant get you here "Consider using an ArrayList of a class (that you create) containing the file name and the InputStream to store this data. ".

Comment: Allow me to clarify. Instead of trying to use a map to store an association between the file name and the input stream, consider creating a class that stores a single file name and a single input stream. Create one of these objects for each of the files (similar to what you do above in adding them to the map), but put them in an ArrayList. You can then iterate over the ArrayList in place of the map, and duplicate filenames will not be replaced.

Comment: Its working almost fine but there is a small problem how can i get values like file.getStream().toArray()[0] and file.getStream().toArray()[5] ???

Comment: why means if i have 10 images then i have to insert like img1 and img6 to db and then img2 and img7.... finally img5 and img10 to DB so that time how can get values like linkedHasMap such as fileMap.values().toArray()[0]; fileMap.values().toArray()[5];

Comment: Since you are now using a class to store the data, we iterate over the objects in the ArrayList. Each object is named `file` of type `FileWithStream`. `file.getName()` returns the name for that given object (the equivalent of fileMap.keys().toArray()[...]), and `file.getStream()` returns the stream for that given object (the equivalent of fileMap().values().toArray()[...]).

Comment: I understand you but i want to get index based values like file.getStream().[0] and file.getStream().[5].how?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to do. Why are you trying to find indices within a stream? `file` refers to a specific uploaded image. The iteration of this object is done (on both parameters) by the for-each loop that surrounds the code. There is no need to do manual iteration within the loop; it is taken care of by the for-each loop itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70786/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-colavitam).

Answer (score 1):

While putting values in map

> ...
>
> fileMap.put(item.getName(), item.getInputStream());
>
> ....

You have kept "File Name" as key and map keep only last added value, in case of duplicate key.

So, I suggest you to replace your file Name with a unique key.

Comment: Now I understand the problem clearly but i cant get you "I suggest you to replace your file Name with a unique key. " you meant that i should upload different name of images??

Answer (score 1):

You need uniqe image name for each image other wise image with same name will overwrite value of old image in your map as keys are unique in map

```
 fileMap.put(item.getName(), item.getInputStream());
```

one solution is you can append current time with your file name to make them unique

```
  fileMap.put((item.getName() + "" + new Date().getTime()), item.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I am getting error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 when i do with your code by uploading same image name

Comment: please post full StackTrace

Comment: Its seems new Date().getTime()) not append and make not duplicate

Comment: Its working fine when i use some variable values dynamically instead of new Date().getTime(). Anyway thanks lot for good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got answer using below code,

```
Connection con1 =null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        int GetUniqueId=0;
        System.out.println("Entered successfully 1:");

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");
            String sql1 ="select contact_id from contacts order by contact_id desc limit 1" ;                          
            stmt = con1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
            if(rst.next())
            {

                //String newone = rst.getString("contact_id");
                GetUniqueId = Integer.parseInt(rst.getString("AutoIncrementValue"));
                System.out.println("Ifffffffffffff"+GetUniqueId);

            }
            else
            {
                GetUniqueId = 0;
                System.out.println("elseeeeeeeeeeee"+GetUniqueId);

            }

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }



final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;

         LinkedHashMap<String, InputStream> fileMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, InputStream>();

        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

            try {
                items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("selected images :"+items);
            if (items != null) {                    
                final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {

                    final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                    if (item.isFormField()) {                       

                    } else {
                    // item.getName() - gives file name
                    GetUniqueId = GetUniqueId+1;

                    String getfirst = item.getName();
                    String [] get = getfirst.split("\\.");
                    System.out.println("splited :"+get[0]);
                    System.out.println("splited :"+get[1]);

                     getchange = get[0];
                     getchange = getchange+""+ GetUniqueId;

                    String addjpg =getchange+"."+get[1];
                    System.out.println("splited finally :"+addjpg);
                     fileMap.put(addjpg, item.getInputStream());

                    listGetImgName.add(addjpg);


                }


                }
            }
        }
```

Its working fine now. Thanks to Mr.Keval and Mr.colavitam

Comment: but wait what will happen when your server restart or some how your uniqueimage variable initialized again than it has value as 0 so you will can have duplicate image names in database ..

Comment: append timestamp with help of new Date().getTime() so that you will have unique image names only ..  i think this should work

Comment: working fine even restart the server but worry about that dublicate image names in DB..!

Comment: that's why i suggest you to use time stamp that will always give you unique value

Comment: you are right but i am getting arrayindexbound error when i use  Date().getTime()

Comment: I think when i use  Date().getTime() there is also same time and getting duplicate values.

Comment: Check my answer now.I tried by Date().getTime() but it gives dupliacte times for same name images so i changed my thought like above updated answer.